# Pycharm Enter Key is not working

Tags: python, pycharm, keymapping

I am facing a very weird problem...

My enter key is not causing a line break in pycharm. When I press enter at the end of a line, the cursor jumps to the front of the next line, without causing a line break.

This suddenly happened, I have no idea why.

I checked my keymap and have reset it, with enter key mapping to enter but this problem still persists.

Does anyone have any solution?

Comment: I've always had very good luck contacting JetBrains tech support when I have problems with PhpStorm.

Comment: They also have a user forum at their site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the reason causing that. Just like to post a possible solution if anyone else is facing similar problems. It appears that my 'use block caret' box was checked.

Go to file -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> 'Use block caret' and uncheck it if it's checked.

Otherwise, it might be the issue with the keymapping. Go to File -> Settings -> Keymap, search for enter and make sure that it is mapped to enter. OR, just reset the keymap by clicking the reset button on the same page.

Comment: I had similar problem but in python comment only - Enter works only at the end of line in comments. This answer does not help on my issue. I have no solution yet.

Answer (score 41):

I had the same issue. I figured that I had pressed the "insert" key in the keyboard by mistake. When I pressed insert again, it went back to normal. Hope this could be an easy debugging effort before going deeper as suggested above. 
Cheers

Comment: Thank you! If only there was a way to forever diable the insert key

Answer (score 5):

Check if Ideavim OR Vimware is running on the bottom right corner of your Pycharm window. Disable it you will be able to add a new line

Comment: In mac there is not insert buttoon

Comment: I had this problem. It was working before the last update. I can't press enter on the console with the Ideavim plugin on. Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 2):

"Insert" button. I had the same issue with Pycharm Enter Key that didn't worked. Insert key on keyboard will solved that, just press "Insert" button on your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I find that it is pycharm new UI bugs.
When I switch to previous ui, all is fine.
And the keymap, should be your os, but this is default ok, so the only issue is new UI has some bugs.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34604353)